# Combining requestFullscreen and F11

Tags: javascript, html, fullscreen

I have a page with a button which will allow the user to set the page to fullscreen. I do this using **requestFullscreen** (actually, **webkitRequestFullScreen** since I'm testing in Chrome, but the question applies generally). All this works fine.

However, users can also use F11 to go to fullscreen and this causes two problems:

1. F11 does not affect the value of **fullscreenElement**, which remains **null** even after F11 has been used to go fullscreen.
2. **exitFullscreen** cannot be used to reverse a fullscreen set by F11 (although the reverse does work - F11 can turn off fullscreen set with **requestFullscreen**).

Is there a way to combine F11 functionality and the Fullscreen API?

Comment: Have you by any chance found something that works? If so could you add this as an answer to your own question?

Comment: Sadly, I've not found an answer. I think it is deliberately impossible, otherwise the page could hijack the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept F11 keyboard events within your application and call the requestFullscreen API instead.  The user should not see any difference whether they use F11, button, link, etc.

```
var isFullScreen = false;
function handleWindowKeydownEvent(event = {}) {
    if(event.code === 'F11') {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(isFullScreen) {
            isFullScreen = false;
            window.document.exitFullscreen().catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        } else {
            isFullScreen = true;
            window.document.documentElement.requestFullscreen().catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
    }
}
window.addEventListener('keydown', handleWindowKeydownEvent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The functionality is different, F11 is the browser's full screen, `requestFullscreen` is the `Dom` full screen display