# Second call to requestFullscreen is denied in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-fullscreen

I am trying to create a simple HTML file that I can use to make one half of my 32:9 widescreen dark (e.g. while watching a video).

I have created this document that works pretty well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>&nbsp;</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
* { background-color: black; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.no-cursor { cursor: none; }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
const MOTION_TIMEOUT = 500;
const FREEZE_TIMEOUT = 1000;
const NO_CURSOR_CLASS = "no-cursor";
var motionTimer, unfreezeTimer, hidden, frozen;
function tryOpenFullscreen(elem) {
    let requestFullscreen = elem.requestFullscreen || elem.mozRequestFullScreen || elem.webkitRequestFullscreen || elem.msRequestFullscreen;

    if (requestFullscreen) {
        try {
            requestFullscreen.call(elem);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Failed to open fullscreen", error);
        }
    } else {
        console.error("Fullscreen not supported");
    }
}
function mouseNotMoved() {
    window.clearTimeout(motionTimer);
    hide();
}
function mouseMoved() {
    if (!frozen) {
        window.clearTimeout(motionTimer);
        show();
        motionTimer = window.setTimeout(mouseNotMoved, MOTION_TIMEOUT);
    }
}
function isInFullscreen() {
    const element = document.fullscreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement || document.msFullscreenElement;
    return element !== undefined && element !== null;
}
function toggleFullscreen() {
    // Toggling fullscreen will trigger mousemove event,
    // so we need to freeze the cursor motion detection for a short time
    window.clearTimeout(unfreezeTimer);
    freeze();
    unfreezeTimer = window.setTimeout(unfreeze, FREEZE_TIMEOUT);

    if (isInFullscreen()) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
    } else {
        tryOpenFullscreen(document.body);
    }
}
function keyPress(event) {
    if (event.key === "Escape") {
        // Exit fullscreen when pressing Escape
        if (isInFullscreen()) {
            toggleFullscreen();
        }
    } else if (event.key === "f") {
        toggleFullscreen();
    } else if (event.key === "F11") {
        // Prevent browser from going fullscreen by pressing F11
        // Using F11 to exit fullscreen is allowed
        if (!isInFullscreen()) {
            event.preventDefault();
            toggleFullscreen();
        }
    }
}
function hide() {
    document.body.classList.add(NO_CURSOR_CLASS);
    hidden = true;
}
function show() {
    document.body.classList.remove(NO_CURSOR_CLASS);
    hidden = false;
}
function freeze() {
    frozen = true;
}
function unfreeze() {
    frozen = false;
}
function init() {
    hidden = true;
    frozen = false;
    document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoved);
    document.body.addEventListener("dblclick", toggleFullscreen);
    window.addEventListener("keydown", keyPress);
    motionTimer = window.setTimeout(mouseNotMoved, MOTION_TIMEOUT);
}
window.addEventListener("load", init);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's basically a blank black page with some `setTimeout` code to hide the cursor when that doesn't move for a bit. And to make the *whole* screen black, I have a method `toggleFullscreen` that determines whether it needs to request or exit the fullscreen, and then calls uses the available `requestFullscreen` method on the `document.body` element, or `document.exitFullscreen()`.

`toggleFullscreen` is called either as the `dblclick` event handler, or from within an event handler for the `keydown` event if the `F` key was pressed. All this works absolutely fine, I can press `F` as often as I want to toggle back and forth.

But now I'm having trouble with adding the last "feature": The default F11 fullscreen mode will reveal a flyout navigation bar when the mouse moves to the top screen border, which is unwanted behavior for my purposes. Hence I would like to use my own `toggleFullscreen` for entering. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73576281/1843468) I am calling `event.preventDefault()` first, and then `toggleFullscreen`.

But here it becomes strange: entering fullscreen this way works, but not if I just left fullscreen with `F11`:

- I can intercept the first `F11` keypress, prevent the browser fullscreen, and go into DOM fullscreen instead.
- I also intercept the second `F11`, but let it exit fullscreen by native means, which works just fine, too.
- When I press `F11` for the third time, `requestFullscreen` throws an error "Fullscreen request denied".

The error comes with a warning "Request for full-screen was denied because Element.mozRequestFullScreen() was not called from inside a short running user-generated event handler." [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23913111/1843468) talks about this error, but I'm not having a 1-second problem I think - the code should take mere milliseconds to get to the request.

What puzzles me is that the `keydown` event handler should tick all the boxes for "short running user-generated event handler" (`event.isTrusted` is true for the F11 event that will cause the throw).

I did some testing and found that requesting fullscreen through `F11` fails if and only if the previous user-generated event was "exit fullscreen through `F11`":

My `keydown` event handler

- works indefinitely when using only `F` to enter and exit
- works indefinitely when using `F11` to enter but `F` to exit
- doesn't work when using `F` to enter and `F11` to exit and then `F11` to enter again
- works indefinitely using just `F11` to enter and exit when I click once before using `F11` to enter

I've tried using `document.focus()` and `document.click()` in an attempt to mimic the effect of the mouse click, but to no avail. I also tried using `preventDefault + toggleFullscreen` for `F11` enter **and** exit, but that doesn't make a difference, either.

The document works in Edge and Chrome, but as Firefox is my default browser, I'd like to fix it for this.